# How do I enable PDO using CentOS?

Tags: php, pdo, centos

When outputting phpinfo(); I can see that PDO is set to '--disable-pdo' in the Configure Command section.  How can I enable this using SSH?

Comment: +1 No reason for the down vote I need a solution to this too

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747136/how-do-i-configure-php-to-enable-pdo-and-include-mysqli-on-centos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
pecl install pdo
```

**EDIT:**

If it is already installed try 
**edit**

```
/etc/php.ini
```

Add this line

```
; Extension PDO
extension=pdo.so
```

**EDIT :**

if you dont have access to php ini try try this in your php aplication

```
if (!extension_loaded('pdo')) 
{
    dl('pdo.so');
}
```

Comment: `dl` function has been removed from some SAPIs in PHP 5.3.
source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php