# How do I configure php to enable pdo and include mysqli on CentOS?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, centos

PHP Version 5.3.3 on CentOS (x86_64, RHEL 6)

Apparently my PHP installation was configured to exclude Mysqli and disable PDO for some reason. Therefore, I believe this is what's causing them to not work when I try to use the php command from the shell. I can load mysqli and pdo via HTTP just fine, but they don't work from shell. How do I enable these components and what are the risks in doing so?

Configure Command:

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
```

Additional .ini files parsed:

```
/etc/php.d/apc.ini, /etc/php.d/bcmath.ini, /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/dba.ini, /etc/php.d/dom.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/gd.ini, /etc/php.d/imap.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/ldap.ini, /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/odbc.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_odbc.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/snmp.ini, /etc/php.d/soap.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/wddx.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlrpc.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php.d/xsl.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

/etc/php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=mysql.so
```

Comment: What's the error message when you are trying to use them?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'pdo_mysql extension is not installed' in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:302

Comment: Can you show your phpinfo() ?

Comment: No, but I can provide you with any specific section.

Comment: Please provide all sections you can show (especially everything which contains PDO and mySQL). If something is missing in phpinfo(), it is hard to spot if you don't share the whole thing.

Comment: on your configure command you are using "'--disable-pdo'"

Answer (score 25):

You might just have to install the packages.

```
yum install php-pdo php-mysqli
```

After they're installed, restart Apache.

```
httpd restart
```

or

```
apachectl restart
```

Comment: Running the install comes back with `Package php-pdo-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Answer (score 3):

mysqli is provided by php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64

You may need to try the following

```
yum install php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

compile PHP manually once uncompressed, go to the php directory and run
./configure  --with-pdo-mysqli=/usr