# CentOS 7: The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, centos7

I've installed  phpmyadmin (4.5.3.1) on CentOS 07 with apache server (httpd-2.4.18) and PHP 7.0.1. I get the error:

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

So I searched the internet for this error and people came with the following solution, which I tried:

Installing the `php-mbstring` and `php-mcrypt` extensions:

```
yum install php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-gd
```

this command returns:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.viethosting.vn
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: mirrors.viethosting.vn
 * updates: mirrors.viethosting.vn

Package php-mbstring-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package php-mcrypt-5.4.16-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package php-gd-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Nothing to do
```

Please help me!

Comment: use "php -m" command to check what modules are enable. You can enable php modules in a) php.ini b) php.d/

Answer (score 6):

I was wondering for like 2 hours for this issue and the only thing I missed was restarting `php-fpm` along with `httpd`.

So this freaking line solved my headache:

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: I missed this step too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your php.ini and make sure it is loading the mbstring extension, or load it at runtime:

Here for the ini extension loading:

[How do I configure php to enable pdo and include mysqli on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747136/how-do-i-configure-php-to-enable-pdo-and-include-mysqli-on-centos)

Here for runtime loading

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php