# How to fix Class 'PDO' not found Error in PHP with redhat server

Tags: php, laravel, devops

My application gives error

> Class PDO not found

If i use `php -m command` it does not list pdo but in that directory has a pdo.so file. In php.ini file i configure extension command for pdo.so. How to fix this issue? My server space doesn't have internet therefore i use rpm installation.

I tried with installing diffrent pdo version using rpm files. but still not working and always give the same error

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320644/how-do-i-enable-pdo-using-centos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable PDO using CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320644/how-do-i-enable-pdo-using-centos)

Comment: In my case i found two php.ini files. php info () shown path is /opt/remi/php56/root/etc and other one located in /etc. when i issue php --ini command in command line it gives Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc if there has aproblem?

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to yum install php-mysql php-pdo. 
Centos does not allow phpenmod commands so you will be required to edit the php.ini file and uncomment the  extension=pdo_mysql.so. 
Then service httpd restart.

Comment: its uncommented. In my case i found two php.ini files. php info () shown path is /opt/remi/php56/root/etc and other one located in /etc. when i issue php --ini command in command line it gives Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc if there has aproblem?

Comment: Typically php -i will serve yoyr php cli and the ini is found in the /etc directory. Restarting apache is a must after editing the ini file. Check if you have a etc/php/modules directory and if you have a pdo-ext or something similar. Failing all this I would recommend upgrading php to php7 and using phpenmod pdo_mysql I believe.